# Javascript date year issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: date

In firefox and IE, I find a bug with the date object.
I need to run a new date and pass a string which I receive from the server. 
So I can not set the year to be 4 characters, I can do regexp but, I want to avoid it.

```
var data = "06/22/12";

var date = new Date(data);

document.write(date);
```

Sat Jun 22 1912 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Standard Time)

The year on the object is 1912 ?!

Any ideas how do I overcome this?

Comment: Do you want all of your year values to be in the 21st century? What about (say) "06/22/72"? Or "06/22/15"?

Comment: well yes in this case i'd like them to be 21st century

Comment: In that case, can't you just *always* add "20" into the right bit of the string? No need for a regex - just use `substring`.

Comment: yes i guess that will work. strange thought that chrome outputs it in the 21st century by default.

Comment: Well, at that point I suspect you're outside specified behaviour, basically...

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript Language Specification 5.1 says in the section about date string format
that the year must be in 4 digits.
(http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

If you use only two digits you are outside the standard and rely on vendor based interpretation. So it's NOT a bug of firefox. The solution is to add the string "20" in front of your date string.

```
var date = new Date("20" + data);
```